# get more data at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having problems trying to run a function when the page is at the very bottom. I am trying to grab more data from my database when the page is at the very bottom.

My code structure looks something like this

```
constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            render_count: 1,
        }
        this.getFeed.bind(this);
    }

componentDidMount(){
        this.getFeed();
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                console.log("you're at the bottom of the page");
                this.setState({render_count: this.state.render_count+1});
                this.getFeed();
            }
        });
    }

getFeed(){//get node.js data}
```

It seems like this.state is null or some reason. Im getting an error 
"Cannot read property 'render_count' of undefined"
Its also not reading this.getFeed either().

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You need to use arrow function instead of a `function()`. Also consider using IntersectionObserver: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Did you define a constuctor for this class component ?

Comment: window.addEventListener('scroll', function () =>{ is giving me an error

Comment: window.addEventListener('scroll', () =>{

Comment: Can I ask what is the best way to remove my eventlistener? Should i do something like this? "componentWillUnmount(){
        window.removeEventListener('scroll');
    }"

Answer (score 0):

You are in a new scope when in `window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {}`. the keyword `this` does not refer anymore to the React class in question, but the eventListner.

This can be fixed with either using an arrow function

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {})
```

Or saving `this` to a variable or constant

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.getFeed();
        const self = this;
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
            if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                console.log("you're at the bottom of the page");
                self.setState({render_count: self.state.render_count+1});
                self.getFeed();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

`function() {}` functions do not capture `this`, which you'll need.

Use an arrow function instead: `() => { ... }`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/51685 for more details.

Ps. Remember to remove that event listener at some point too.